# Match nodes where all relations satisfy constraints

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm looking to find nodes that have relations where all relations satisfy that constraint. the exact example is do you have a relation in a list.

the graph is bascially cocktails, with the relations being ingredients. given a list of ingredients i want to know what I can make.

```
with ['Sweet Vermouth', 'Gin', 'Campari', 'Bourbon'] as list
...
should return Negroni, Boulevardier, ...
```

I've been finding this tricky because we want to make sure that all relations of a node satisfy the constraint, but the number of **nodes could very easily be a subset** of the list and **not an exact match** to the ingredient list.

this is the best I've done so far, and it only works if you have all the ingredients, but nothing extra.

```
with ['Sweet Vermouth', 'Gin', 'Campari', 'Bourbon'] as list
MATCH (n:Cocktail)-[h:HAS]-(x)
WITH list, count(list) AS lth, n, COLLECT(DISTINCT x.name) AS cx, collect(DISTINCT h) as hh
WHERE ALL (i IN list WHERE i IN cx)
RETURN n
```

I'ved looked at stackoverflow.com/a/62053139/974731. I don't think it solves my problem

[image]

as you can see the addition of Bourbon removes the Negroni, which shouldn't happen since all we've done is add an ingredient to our bar.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053139/974731

Comment: I don't think those answers work. I've played with that already. I'll update the question with what I'm seeing.

Comment: If `MATCH (n:Cocktail {name:'Negroni')-[:HAS]-({name: 'Bourbon'}) return n` returns nothing, then my query is working correctly.

Comment: okay, then I'm explaining this poorly. I want to return all nodes where relations are a subset of the given list. Basically to answer the question. Do you have the ingredients to make this.

I posted a query that works, but I'd love some advice on making that cleaner

Comment: OK, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return all cocktails whose `needed` ingredients are in the `have` list.

```
WITH ['Sweet Vermouth', 'Gin', 'Campari', 'Bourbon'] as have
MATCH (c:Cocktail)-[:HAS]->(x)
WITH have, c, COLLECT(x.name) AS needed
WHERE ALL(n IN needed WHERE n IN have)
RETURN c
```

Or, if you pass `have` as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/):

```
MATCH (c:Cocktail)-[:HAS]->(x)
WITH c, COLLECT(x.name) AS needed
WHERE ALL(n IN needed WHERE n IN $have)
RETURN c
```

Answer (score 0):

It's terribly hacky, but this is where I got

```
with ['Sweet Vermouth', 'Gin', 'Campari', 'Bourbon'] as list
call {
  match (ali:Cocktail)--(ii:Ingredient) //pull all nodes
  return ali, count(ii) as needed // get count for needed ingredients
}
MATCH (ali)--(i:Ingredient)
WHERE i.name in list // get ingredients that are in the list

WITH distinct ali.name as name, count(ali.name) as available, needed
WHERE available = needed
RETURN name;
```