# Neo4j query concerning two elements

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need help trying to do a query in Neo4j that I can't seem to figure out. The query is to return all cakes that contain both the ingredients: Milk and Cream.

Below is a snippet of a cake node and the ingredients (There are more ingredients and cakes but I didn't post them here as they are all formatted the same):

```SQL
  (brownies:Cake {name: "Brownies"}),
  (brownies)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 50, unit: "grams"}]->(white),
  (brownies)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 250, unit: "grams"}]->(selfraising),
  (brownies)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: .5, unit: "grams"}]->(salt),
  (brownies)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 125, unit: "grams"}]->(sugar),
  (brownies)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 250, unit: "grams"}]->(cocoa),
  (brownies)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 125, unit: "grams"}]->(lemonade),
  (brownies)-[:CONTAINS {quantity: 125, unit: "grams"}]->(cola),
  (brownies)-[:GARNISHED_WITH {how: "chopped on top"}]->(cherry),
  (brownies)-[:GARNISHED_WITH {how: "chopped on top"}]->(orange),


  (limeJuice:Ingredient {name: "lime juice"}),
  (cranberryJuice:Ingredient {name: "cranberry juice"}),
  (lemonJuice:Ingredient {name: "lemon juice"}),
  (orangeJuice:Ingredient {name: "orange juice"}),
  (tomatoJuice:Ingredient {name: "tomato juice"}),
  (lemonade:Ingredient {name: "lemonade"}),
  (soda:Ingredient {name: "soda water"}),
  (spice:Ingredient {name: "spice water"}),
  (cola:Ingredient {name: "cola"}),
```

Neo4j seems to have trouble identifying ingredients but I'm not entirely sure that my query is formatted correctly regardless, here is what I have so far:

```
MATCH(x:Cake)-[:CONTAINS]-> (Ingredient: "milk" or "cream") Return x
```

Comment: Your `(:Ingredient)` node query is incorrect. Take a look at the `WHERE ... IN...` clause, which is where you can check for multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ingredient` node check is problematic. Needs to be more like:

```
MATCH(x:Cake)-[:CONTAINS]-> (i:Ingredient)
WHERE i.name IN ['milk', 'cream']
Return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the cakes that contain ALL the ingredients from a list:

```
MATCH (cake:Cake)
WHERE ALL(x IN ['milk', 'cream'] WHERE (cake)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Ingredient{name: x}))
RETURN cake
```